# Wall anchor is off by a slight amount

Tags: drywall, drywall-anchor

I'm hanging a mirror on the wall (drywall) that has rigid hangers on the back.  I'm using a heavy duty wall anchor and measured but when I drilled, the screw is about an 1/8 of an inch off and the mirror bracket will not slip on to the screwhead.  Can I tap the screw/anchor over a small amount so that it fits or do I have to repair the wall and start all over again?  The mirror isn't that heavy and weighs less than 10 lbs. (maybe around 7 lbs).  The studs don't line up with the wall correctly for centering the mirrors aesthetically, so screwing into the studs wasn't an option.

Comment: Can you shift the anchor on the mirror? Or attach very short (and different size) loops to the existing anchors?

Comment: A picture of this would be helpful.

Comment: Shifting the mount on the mirror is the way to go.... Drywall can't take that kind of adjustment